# How to compile spec256k1 into a shared object?

Tags: c++, ruby, compilation, shared-libraries, bitcoin

I'm trying to use a Ruby wrapper that requires an `.so` file to run. I have the [C++ project](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) that I want to compile into the `.so` so I can link to it in Ruby. I don't really know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to build the C++ project, and with the resulting object file `object.o`, run `g++ -shared object.o`. The resulting `a.out` file is the shared object file.